# Git: Revert a single file to its last commit

Tags: git

I want to revert a file to its state on its last commit.

I have modified, added and committed other files. 
But there is that one file that I didn't stage.

I want to revert it's state (only the state of that file) to the last commit that that file was committed.

In other words, I just want to ignore the last changes made to that file and restore it to the last point it participated in a commit.

Comment: `git checkout commit-hash -- file` ?

Comment: You did not commit the file?

Comment: Note that the suggested duplicate above is about copying out a specific *committed* version; you've asked to copy out the *current* committed version, which is easy to name via `HEAD`, but also suggested that you could take the current *staged* version—which Git staged on its own when Git extracted the commit you're working on—which is what [glco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61735720/1256452) does.

Comment: Thank you @torek, that's exactly what I wanted to do. But I thought that there was an easier way, more file directed to do that.

Comment: Anyway, don't know why they closed the topic, it didn't seen to me that its the same as the other. Even if they have the same answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use:

```
    git checkout <file-with-path>
```

Or

```
    git restore <file-with-path>
```

Git checkout would work if you had already committed the file. If the file was already staged you could add --staged flag to git restore to restore it as well.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore

Comment: This is not quite what the OP asked to do, but will actually work fine given the OP's description. Be careful with `git restore --staged`, however, which does not update the work-tree copy; using `git restore --staged --work-tree` updates *both* copies but requires the `--source` option as well. The command `git restore --source HEAD -s -w path/to/file` does the same thing as `git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file` and is also suitable here.

Comment: Sorry, why my git doesn't recognize restore as a command?

Comment: Anyway, the git checkout <file-with-path> command worked, thank you @gIco